# c++ smart pointers and passing to functions

Tags: c++, pointers

I am learning about smart pointers and am confused about some things. Lets say i have a linked list structure like this

```
struct Node {
  shared_ptr<Node> next;
  int data;

  Node(int val): next(nullptr), data(val) {}
};
```

is it good enough to keep the next as shared_ptr. i think it should probably be a unique_ptr right ?

also in the main i create the head as follows :

```
auto head = make_shared<Node>(4);
```

again, this should be make_unique() right ? Now i pass this head around to a bunch of different functions. So what should be the signature of that function ? I read that smart pointers should not be passed to functions (due to performance reasons and basically it doesn't make sense). so keeping that in mind how do i pass the head created above ? the only way i use head in any of the functions is to create a pointer curr to it and then use it iterate over the list. 
    auto curr = head;

Comment: Smart pointers and "smart" containers such as `std::list` work in tandem to make programming easier. Mixing smart pointers and homebrew C-style linked lists results in nothing good happening.

Comment: There are _some_ functions where it is unnecessary and wasteful to pass a smart pointer. And I'd avoid using them as a "next" pointer in a linked list. But if you never pass a smart pointer to _any_ function whatsoever (including constructors and mutator), I think they'd be quite useless, Where did you get that advice?

Comment: `shared_ptr` and `unique_ptr` are about *ownership* semantics. I don't think a  `Node` *owning* the next `Node` would make much sense. If you need a linked list data structure, I'd say go with `std::list` or `std::forward_list`. If you want to implement it yourself, you probably have to choose some other type of smart pointer, or just use raw pointers.

Comment: I'll warn you, things can get a little odd if you do this with `unique_ptr`, as they are not copyable, but are movable, Coding a simple linked list with a few basic operations will likely expose what I describe. It is doable, but some things aren't immediately intuitive until you *really* understand how smart pointer ownership and restrictions work. A simple "print the list" function is a great example. Try it. Then use `std::list<>`, `std::deque<>` etc., whatever container is appropriate for your needs.

Comment: I am just trying to figure out smart pointer for fun. Of course I can use the standard library for list etc but that is not my intention. I am just trying out details about smart pointers. And I made the next pointer a smart pointer so once i delete the head, it will delete all subsequent nodes. is my understanding correct in this respect ?       I got confused after reading this http://herbsutter.com/2013/06/05/gotw-91-solution-smart-pointer-parameters/

Comment: Where did you read that smart pointers should not be passed to functions?

Comment: Why conflate the two things?  If you want to understand `unique_ptr` vs `shared_ptr`, consider/explore their properties without bringing lists into the picture.  If you want to call functions passing them a pointer or reference to an object, the critical thing is whether any other ownership of the object could be relinquished while the function is running (triggering destruction) - if so do some locking and/or clone a `shared_ptr`.  If the called function may want to share in the ownership, passing a `shared_ptr` is convenient, and `enable_shared_from_this` is an alternative.